# Xamarin Show iOS UIDatePicker from Image Tap

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

So I am using Xamarin and trying to create an image renderer that when tapped will show the UIDatePicker for iOS.  I have the renderer working great for Android, but I can not get the date picker to display on iOS.  My code is below for the renderer and I debugged into it and I get all the way through mTextField.BecomeFirstResponder(); which I "thought" would make the date picker display.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I just need that picker to display on the screen.  Once I can get it to display I can handle it like I want.

```
private void _DatePickerHasBeenTapped( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if( mDatePickerDialog != null )
        {
            mDatePickerDialog.TouchCancel -= _DatePickerDialogOnCancelEvent;
            mDatePickerDialog.ValueChanged -= _DatePickerDialogOnValueChanged;
        }

        var date = mDatePicker.PickerDate == DateTime.MinValue
            ? DateTime.Today
            : mDatePicker.PickerDate;


        mTextField = new UITextField();

        mDatePickerDialog = new UIDatePicker { Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date, TimeZone = new NSTimeZone( "UTC" ) };

        mDatePickerDialog.ValueChanged += _DatePickerDialogOnValueChanged;
        mDatePickerDialog.SetDate( date.ToNSDate(), false );

        var width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        var toolbar = new UIToolbar( new RectangleF( 0, 0, (float)width, 44 ) ) { BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default, Translucent = true };
        var spacer = new UIBarButtonItem( UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace );
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem( UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, ( o, a ) => mDatePickerDialog.ResignFirstResponder() );

        toolbar.SetItems( new[] { spacer, doneButton }, false );

        mTextField.InputView = mDatePickerDialog;
        mTextField.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;

        if( mTextField.CanBecomeFirstResponder )
        {
            mTextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method would work if the `UITextField` was actually being displayed. Now you could *hack* it by adding the UITextField to the VC View hierarchy but offsetting it with a negative cgrect to get it off screen and removing it after in the `UIBarButtonItem` handler:

```
var mTextField = new UITextView(new CGRect(-1000, -1000, 10, 10));
yourViewController.Add(mTextField);
```

Note: I've seen responder failures with off-screen controls and avoid them when I need them to be faux responders, but I know others that do it... user beware... :-/

Or:

You could design a UIViewController either programmatically or from a storyboard that contains the picker and a *close* button and present that when the user taps your image. Catch the tap on the close button, dismiss the controller and send your picker date somewhere...

Or:

For something like this I normally use a popover style view controller.

#### Example:

```
var parentVC = this; // This would the "main" Form's ViewController, obtain it within your renderer

PopoverDelegate popoverDelegate = null;
var datePicker = new UIDatePicker(new CGRect(0, 0, parentVC.View.Frame.Width, 300));
popoverDelegate = new PopoverDelegate(datePicker, (date) =>
{
    // Post the date change back to Forms via an event, etc... 
    Console.WriteLine($"Date Choosen: {date}");
    datePicker.Dispose();
    popoverDelegate.Dispose();
});
using (var popOverStyleVC = new UIViewController
{
    ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
})
{
    var pc = popOverStyleVC.PopoverPresentationController;
    {
        pc.Delegate = popoverDelegate;
        pc.SourceView = parentVC.View;
        pc.SourceRect = imageButton.Frame; // a CGRect where you want the popup arrow to point
    }
    popOverStyleVC.PreferredContentSize = datePicker.Frame.Size;
    popOverStyleVC.View.Add(datePicker);
    parentVC.PresentViewController(popOverStyleVC, true, null);
}
```

#### Results in:

[image]

The missing part from above it the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` as you ***have*** to return `UIModalPresentationStyle.None` via `UIModalPresentationStyle GetAdaptivePresentationStyle` other the popover is not displayed properly, this is also where I catch the dismissal and provide a callback with the date.

#### UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate:

```
public class PopoverDelegate : UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
{
    public delegate void DatePicked(NSDate date);
    UIDatePicker datePicker;
    DatePicked datePicked;

    public PopoverDelegate(UIDatePicker datePicker, DatePicked datePicked)
    {
        this.datePicked = datePicked;
        this.datePicker = datePicker;
    }

    public override UIModalPresentationStyle GetAdaptivePresentationStyle(UIPresentationController forPresentationController)
    {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None;
    }

    public override void DidDismissPopover(UIPopoverPresentationController popoverPresentationController)
    {
        datePicked(datePicker.Date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will give this a try.  In the beginning of your response I don't understand your remark about not having buttons for the user to choose being done.  I am creating a toolbar with a done button so that would be the button the user could click.

I am still confused on why what I am doing doesn't work .  The building of the date picker dialog is very similar to Xamarin forms date picker renderer.  I just don't know why it won't show.  Is it because my UITextField is not on the screen/visible?

Comment: @theDoke Missed the `InputAccessoryView`, need mor' coffee ;-) That would work, but you would need to ResignFirstResponder on the UITextField not the picker and of course capture the picker date at that point. What you have would work if the control (image-based uiview?) was an input control on the view hierarchy, Now you could *hack it* by adding the UITextField to VC view but offsetting it with a negative cgrect to get it off screen and removing it after in the UIBarButtonItem handler. I tend to avoid those off-screen UIViews as I've seen them randomly fail...